How can I show that $\mathbb{E}(T)=\frac{a^2}{\sigma^2}$?

Let $(X_i)_{i=1,2,...}$ be a sequence of iid random variables such that $\mathbb{P}(X_i=\pm 1)=\frac{1}{2}$ and with $\operatorname{Var}(X_i)=\sigma^2>0$. Set $S_t=\sum_{k=1}^t X_i$ for $t=1,2,...$ and $S_0=0$. Let $(\mathcal{F}_t)$ be the natural filtration of $S$. I want to show that $\mathbb{E}(T)=\frac{a^2}{\sigma^2}$ where $T:=\inf\{t\geq 0: |S_t|\geq a\}$. I need to use that $Y_t:=S^2_t-\sigma^2t$ is a martingale.

Since $Y$ is a martingale we know that $\mathbb{E}(Y_{T\wedge t})=0$ and on the other hand \begin{align}\mathbb{E}(Y_{T\wedge t})&=\mathbb{E}(S^2_{T\wedge t}-\sigma^2(T\wedge t))\\
&=\mathbb{E}(S^2_{T\wedge t})-\sigma^2 \mathbb{E}(T\wedge t)+\sigma^2\\
&=\mathbb{E}(S^2_T 1_{\{T<t\}})+\mathbb{E}(S^2_t 1_{\{t<T\}})-\sigma^2 \mathbb{E}(T\wedge t)+\sigma^2\\
&=a^2 \mathbb{P}(T<t)+\mathbb{E}(S^2_t 1_{\{t<T\}})-\sigma^2 \mathbb{E}(T\wedge t)+\sigma^2\end{align}
Taking on both sides the limit $t\rightarrow \infty$ and using the fact that $T$ is an a.s.
finite stopping time we get $$\mathbb{E}(Y_t)=a^2-\sigma^2\mathbb{E}(T)+\sigma^2$$
Combining those two facts we get $0=a^2-\sigma^2\mathbb{E}(T)+\sigma^2$ and thus $\mathbb{E}(T)=\frac{a^2+\sigma^2}{\sigma^2}$. But this is now what I want. Can someone help me?

Where did the extra $\sigma^{2}$ come from in the second line of your argument?

There are other justifications that have to be made if you want to do it rigorously.
For example, what is allowing you to conclude that $E(T\wedge t)\xrightarrow{t\to\infty}=E(T)$?
What is allowing you to conclude that $E(S_{t}^{2}\mathbf{1}_{t<T})\xrightarrow{t\to\infty} 0$?
Firstly, you have correctly noted that $E(Y_{T\wedge t})=0$
This tells you that $E(S_{T\wedge t}^{2}-\sigma^{2}(T\wedge t))=E(S_{T\wedge t}^{2})-\sigma^{2}E(T\wedge t)=0$ for all $t\in\Bbb{N}$
Now, note that $|S_{T\wedge t}|^{2}\leq a^{2}$ for all $t$. Also, $S_{T\wedge t}^{2}\xrightarrow{t\to\infty}a^{2}$ almost surely as $T$ is almost surely finite.
(i.e. almost surely, after a certain time $t$, $S_{T\wedge t}^{2}=a^2$ for all large enough $t$)
Thus, by Dominated Convergence Theorem, $E(S_{T\wedge t}^{2})\to a^{2}$.
Now $T\wedge t$ is an increasing random variable which converges to $T$ almost surely as $t\to\infty$ and hence, by Monotone Convergence Theorem, you have that $E(T\wedge t)\to E(T)$.
This tells you that $a^{2}-\sigma^{2}E(T)=0$ which gives you the required result.
NOTE: The above is valid for $a$ being a positive integer. In case $a$ is not an integer, then $T$ can be redefined to be $\inf\{t\geq 0: |S_{t}|\geq \lfloor a\rfloor +1\}$ and then, you'll have $E(T)=\dfrac{(\lfloor a\rfloor +1)^{2}}{\sigma^{2}}$ by following the same steps.
